# Update a parameter value in Brightway

Tags: brightway

It seems to be a simple question but I have a hard time to find an answer to it. I already have a project with several parameters (project and database parameters). I would like to obtain the LCA results for several scenarios with my parameters having different values each time. I was thinking of the following simple procedure:

1. change the parameters' value,
2. update the exchanges in my project,
3. calculate the LCA results.

I know that the answer should be in the [documentation](https://brightway2-parameters.readthedocs.io/) somewhere, but I have a hard time to understand how I should apply it to my ProjectParameters, DatabaseParameters and ActivityParameters.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Thanks to @Nabla, I was able to come up with this:

*For ProjectParameter*

```
for pjparam in ProjectParameter.select():
    if pjparam.name=='my_param_name':
        break
pjparam.amount = 3
pjparam.save()
bw.parameters.recalculate()
```

*For DatabaseParameter*

```
for dbparam in DatabaseParameter.select():
    if dbparam.name=='my_param_name':
        break
dbparam.amount = 3
dbparam.save()
bw.parameters.recalculate()
```

*For ActivityParameter*

```
for param in ActivityParameter.select():
    if param.name=='my_param_name':
        break    
param.amount = 3
param.save()
param.recalculate_exchanges(param.group)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could import `DatabaseParameter` and `ActivityParameter` iterate until you find the parameter you want to change, update the value, save it and recalculate the exchanges. I think you need to do it in tiers. First you update the *project* parameters (if any) then the *database* parameters that may depend on project parameters and then the *activity* parameters that depend on them.

A simplified case without project parameters:

```py
from bw2data.parameters import ActivityParameter,DatabaseParameter

# find the database parameter to be updated
for dbparam in DatabaseParameter.select():
    if (dbparam.database == uncertain_db.name) and (dbparam.name=='foo'):
        break

dbparam.amount = 3
dbparam.save()

#there is also this method if foruma depend on something else 
#dbparam.recalculate(uncertain_db.name)

# here updating the exchanges of a particular activity (act)

for param in ActivityParameter.select():
    if param.group == ":".join(act.key):
        param.recalculate_exchanges(param.group)
```

you may want to update all the activities in the project instead of a single one like in the example. you just need to change the condition when looping through the activity parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I am now able to complete the first step for my `DatabaseParameter`. But when it comes to `param.recalculate_exchanges(param.group)`, I get the error `AttributeError: 'DatabaseParameter' object has no attribute 'recalculate_exchanges'`

Comment: ok, I've adapted the response for DatabaseParameters

Comment: For me, the condition `if param.group == ":".join(act.key):` does no catch any parameter in any activity. But I found a way to solve this and to update everything (I think?):
`for dbparam in DatabaseParameter.select():
    if (dbparam.name=='my_param_name':
        break

dbparam.amount = 3
dbparam.save()
bw.parameters.recalculate()`